# Change color of checkbox inside CListCtrl

Tags: c++, mfc, clistctrl

I'm trying to find a way to change background color of checkbox inside `CListCtrl`, please help me to find a working solution. Maybe there is some way to work with `CListCtrl` subitems inside the `OnCtlColor` function? I can change the text color and backcolor of `CListCtrl`, but can't find a way how to change the checkboxes background color...

```
HBRUSH CZilchDlg::OnCtlColor(CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor) 
{
    
    HBRUSH hbr = CDialog::OnCtlColor(pDC, pWnd, nCtlColor);
 
    
    if ( nCtlColor== CTLCOLOR_LISTBOX)
    {
        
        pDC->SetTextColor(RGB(255, 0, 0));
        pDC->SetBkMode(TRANSPARENT);
                pDC->SetBkColor(RGB(0,255,0));
        
        hbr = m_brush;
    }
 
    return hbr;
}
```

Comment: I saw this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ebec9847-e440-44e9-a53a-3dd827210947/custom-checkboxes-in-clistctrl?forum=vcmfcatl Don't know if you have tried that?

Comment: Thank you, I saw this post, but code sample provided there is not full, I don’t understand how to use it to change checkbox color

Comment: The clue is in that link. Any how, check this answer which shows you how to use your own image list with a `CListCtrl`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22531065/how-to-add-images-to-clistctrl-in-mfc

Comment: I am sorry for my misunderstanding, but i need to change only the background color of checkbox inside the CListCtrl i dont need to load images. Could anybody please give a code sample wich technic i should use to achieve my goal

Comment: List controls (CListCtrl) and list boxes (CListBox) are different types of controls. So, for list controls, you need to attack it differently using NM_CUSTOMDRAW or something like that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10649836/how-to-handle-nm-customdraw-event-to-retrieve-list-items